# What is the xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts "Property" value to bind left-click?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I am using xfce4 and I would like to set a keyboard shortcut for `<Primary><Shift>` + left-click.

I would like to set this keyboard combo to run `xfce4-screenshooter -r`.

On compiz, I believe left-click is "Button1" but I have tried that and it doesn't work.

Mouse clicks don't seem to register when "detecting" and there are no default shortcuts that use a mouse-click value.

Does anybody know how to set or bind a keyboard shortcut to right or left click on xfce4?

Comment: To this date, binding a mouse click is *not* possible in Xfce. For workarounds, see [this old forum thread](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6800) and [this post on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/545944/37165). Both suggested to use `xbindkeys`, etc.